# Is it easy to get snowboard/ski hire in Borovets without prior booking?

Tags: winter-sports, bulgaria, skiing

We're off to Borovets skiing in a month or so. We want to book ski/snowboard hire, passes, etc but finding the websites difficult to navigate.

Does anyone have experience of getting ski hire on arrival?

Is it easy, reasonably priced, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Borovets you'll find it very easy to rent skis or other equipment you might need. Most if not all of the places that rent skis speak multiple languages and will be clearly marked around the resort. In case you find difficulties, just ask anyone around in English and they should be able to help you. Expect around 20 BGN/day for ski + boot + poles rental.